# How to display filename and latest created date in batchfile

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-scripting

I created one batch script by running following batch script. It displays latest .bak file created and that output store in one file.

Now I want one additional attribute of Created Date of that file but failed to retrieve it. I hope someone can guide me.

here is the sample code of my script

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /D %%a in (C:\BACKUP\*) do (
    SET var="%%a"
    echo The ServerName is :: !var! >>1.txt & echo.>>1.txt  
    for /R /D %%b in ("%%a\*") do (
        SET var1="%%b"
        SET var2="%%~nb"        
        echo the subfolder of  !var! is:: '' !var2!>>1.txt & echo.>>1.txt           
        for /f %%x in ('DIR /B /A-D /OD /T:C "%%b\*.bak"') do (set 
            bakFile="%%x"
        )
        echo The Latest Bak File is :: !bakFile!  >> 1.txt & echo.>>1.txt
    )
)
```

Comment: I have edited your code to fix the unbalanced parentheses and to indent it for readability. I did not however fix the obvious error line `9` to `10`, _I'll leave that to you to sort out_! Additionally, you state that you failed to retrieve the creation date of the file, but looking at your code it appears that it doesn't even attempt to retrieve it. Please update your question by [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50760255/edit), to include the code which has failed, so that we can help you with it. _Failure to do that means that youre requesting somebody to do your work for you!_

Comment: if you are satisfied with the "last write access", simply use `%%~tx` (it's not "created" date, but *should* be sufficient for a `.bak` file). Getting "last write access" date is a bit more code (parsing `dir` output or parsing `wmic datafile where name="C:\\path\\file.ext" get CreationDate')

Comment: @stephan i tried one simple program which not go in to subfolder and it works perfectly i am able to get fetch date and filename but when it goes to subfolder then it will failed to retrieve time

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell will give you direct access to the `CreationTime`. Save the following script in a file such as `latestbak.ps1`.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param()

Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path 'C:\src\t' |
    ForEach-Object {
        $ServerName = $_.Fullname
        Write-Information $("The ServerName is :: `"{0}`"" -f $($ServerName))
        Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse -Path $ServerName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
            ForEach-Object {
                Write-Information $("the subdirectory of  `"{0}`" is:: '' `"{1}`"" -f $($(Split-Path  -Path $_.FullName), $_.Name))
                Get-ChildItem -File -Path $_.FullName -Filter '*.ps1' | Sort-Object -Property CreationTime | Select-Object -Last 1 |
                    ForEach-Object {
                        Write-Information $("The latest Bak File is :: `"{0}`"" -f $($_.FullName))
                    }
            }
    }
```

Run this from a PowerShell console using:

```
.\latestbak.ps1 -InformationAction Continue 6>1.txt
```

Alternatively, from a cmd shell using:

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command ".\latestbak.ps1 -InformationAction Continue 6>1.txt"
```